Jetpack Compose Modifier wrapContentMaxHeight
I know that I can use Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.8f) to use 80% of the available height.
However I'd like to have a Modifier that wraps the content height but does not exceed 80% of the available height. So if the content only covers 40% of the available height that's fine. If it covers 90%, I only want 80%. Is there any way I can compose such a Modifier?

You can use the layout modifier, which allows you changing how the wrapped element is measured and laid out. While fillMaxHeight sets the Constraints.minHeight and the Constraints.maxHeight to be equal to the Constraints.maxHeight multiplied by fraction, you only want to do that for maxHeight and not minHeight. With layout, you can do exactly that:
Box(
  modifier = Modifier.layout { measurable, constraints ->
    val adjustedConstraints = if (constraints.maxHeight != Constraints.Infinity) {
      constraints.copy(maxHeight = (constraints.maxHeight * 0.8).roundToInt())
    } else {
      constraints
    }
    val placeable = measurable.measure(adjustedConstraints)
    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
      placeable.place(0, 0)
    }
  }
)

You can easily extract that to reusable Modifier extension function with fraction parameter.

While i'm not aware of a modifier which can do that you could use a Column with weights, but set fill to false:
@Composable
fun EightyTwenty(
    eighty: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
    twenty: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(modifier) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(8f, fill = false),
            content = eighty,
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(2f),
            content = twenty
        )
    }
}

I've created a preview so you can test it easily:
@Preview
@Composable
private fun EightyTwentyPreview() {

    EightyTwenty(
        eighty = {
            TextColumn(
                lines = 100, // alternatively, use 10 for short content
                backgroundColor = Color.Green
            )
        },
        twenty = {
            TextColumn(
                lines = 10,
                backgroundColor = Color.Red
            )
        },

        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(300.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
    )
}

@Composable
private fun TextColumn(
    lines: Int,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .background(backgroundColor)
    ) {
        repeat(lines) {
            Text("This is test ${it + 1} of $lines")
        }
    }
}




Yes, you can compose a Modifier in Jetpack Compose to achieve the desired behavior. To wrap content height but limit it to a maximum of 80% of the available height, you can use the Modifier.heightIn() function with dynamic values provided by LocalDensity and BoxWithConstraints.

Do you have an example?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
